# How do I specify a line to print in an AWK script?

Tags: printing, awk, line, sequence

I have to make an awk script which take events that had occurred in 3 consecutive days, I have a column with days and a column with months, I'm testing them to analyze the sequence and I don't know how to print the lines. Here's what I have:

```
BEGIN{
    count=0;
    dia=0;

}

{
    day=$2; 
    month=$3;

    if(dia==31 && day==1 && month==02 || month==04 || month==06 || month==09 || month==11){
        count+=1
    }
    else if(dia==30 && day==1 && month==03 || month==05 || month==07 || month==08 || month==10 || month==12){
        count+=1
    }
    else if(dia==28 && day==1 && month==03){
        count+=1
    }
    else if(day==dia+1){
        count+=1;
    }
    else {
        count=0;
    }
    if(count==3){
        for(i=NR-4;i<=NR;i++){
            print ??? (line i)
        }
        count=0;
    }
    dia=day;
}
```

I tought make something with arrays, but I believe if I could print these way it would be easier.

My input data are files like these:

> 83032  18  07  0000 -99 20.4 -99 7.6  6.88
>   83032  27  08  0000 -99 30.6 -99 6.1  21
>   83037  **29**  06  0000 -99 20.4 -99 4.9  11.12
>   83037  **30**  06  0000 -99 18.7 -99 0.5  11.2
>   83037  **01**  07  0000 -99 33.5 -99 7.7  24
>   83037  05  07  0000 -99 23.3 -99 10.1  11.28
>   83037  17  07  0000 -99 21.1 -99 10.2  11.1
>   83037  18  07  0000 -99 20.7 -99 7.1  11.26

and I want to take just lines which have 3 consecutive days (2nd column), making an output like this:

> 83037  29  06  0000 -99 20.4 -99 4.9  11.12
>   83037  30  06  0000 -99 18.7 -99 0.5  11.2
>   83037  01  07  0000 -99 33.5 -99 7.7  24

Comment: Edit your question to include clear, precise, testable sample input and expected output. Your script has variables named `dia` and `day` - is that a typo and it's supposed to be a single variable? If not, what do they mean? Do you have (or can get) GNU awk (try `awk --version`)?

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do correctly it may be easier to convert day/month to a serial number and do unbroken sequence/gap analysis on one monotonous sequence.

Comment: @karakfa i don't know the funcions and process you mentioned, how can i apply it in my script?

Comment: OK, so the word you want is "consecutive" not "sequenced" but what does "which have 3 or 5 sequenced (consecutive) days" mean? If you have 3 you print 3 lines but if you have 4 you print 3 lines (which ones - the first 3 or the last 3 or the first 3 and then the last 3?) and then if you have 5 consecutive days do you print groups of 3 and then a group of 5 or do something else? You need to edit your question to explain your requirements more clearly and provide more sample input and expected output that at the very least covers the cases of 3, 4, and 5, consecutive lines.

Comment: O, sorry @EdMorton i realize now that i can't print the two cases at the same script, because it will make one output file. Sorry about my english to, i'm trying :D i fix the question about the 3 or 5 day... i have to test the 2nd column  to know if it is consecutive or not, and after know that it is (count==3), i want to print the last three lines (consecutive lines). Thks for the pacient.

Comment: You can do whatever you want in one script, it doesn't need to output everything to 1 file, but it's still not clear what you want. If you had, say, 6 consecutive days on lines 3,4,5,6,7,8 would you want to print lines 3,4,5 then 4,5,6 then 5,6,7 then 6,7,8 to output file 1 (the 3-line output file) and additionally print lines 3,4,5,6,7 then 4,5,6,7,8 to output file 2 (the 5-line output file) or do something else? Again, a more representative input/output set would help a lot.

Comment: i'm changed my script, because in fact, i just want to know if i have an "event" in my datas that occurs 3 and 5 days consecutively. to be more accurate, i was tryng to take all the consecutive days. for me it's not important if they occur in 7 days consecutively, because i'm tryng to classify just the event. i was taking every line (of event) just to have a more accurate data to work with...

Comment: You've completely lost me. Maybe someone else can figure out what you're trying to do. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can build on top of this.  Calculates a day number compares with the previous one, if three consecutive happens print the buffered rows.  Note that this is not robust also you need to perhaps group by the first identifier field since the days might be valid within one group.  Also need to consider leap years.  Anyway, for the given input this works

```
BEGIN {                                              # days in months
   split("31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31", m, ",")
}
{
   n = $2 + 0                                        # calculate day num
   for (i = 1; i < $3 + 0; i++) {
      n += m[i]
   }
}

p + 1 == n {                                         # if next value
   c++                                               # increment counter
   a[c] = $0                                         # save record 
}

{ p = n }                                            # set to previous

c == 3  {                                            # print rows if reached target
   for (i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
      print a[i]
   }
   delete a                                          # clear for next round
   c = 0
}
```

Comment: Ohh... thank you. It worked. I changed a little, because my data are bigger than the one i showed, so i have to set c=0 for the counter, to find the others patterns. bye.

Comment: @lazzari26 As a courtesy to the answer's author, you should at least a) upvote it and b) accept it (by clicking the check mark next to the answer).